# Replace a date in file to another date using sed not workiing

Tags: bash, date, sed

I need to replace a date in file on device to another date . But the following sed command for string replace  is not working .

```
path= "/var/local"
last_date=d("cat /var/local”)-----06/24/18 date i
previous_date=(datetime.strptime(last_date, '%m/%d/%y')-timedelta(1)).strftime("%m/%d/%y”)--output --06/23/18
"sed -i 's/%s/%s/g' %s" % (last_date, previous_date, file)
```

This Sed give output as 24/24/18. It is not replacing the complete date

Comment: Please wrap your samples with code tags in your post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you're effectively running the following command:

```
sed -i "s/06/24/18/06/23/18/g" /var/local
```

As you can see, the problem is that you're not escaping the slashes in your regex.

The shortest fix would be to call `.replace("/", "\\/")` on both `last_date` and `previous_date` in your python code.

However, since you're already using Python, you might do better to only use pure Python, and not use sed at all.

Comment: Or use another delimiter in the `s` command in `sed`, e.g. `sed -i 's@%s@%s@g'`.